# InputMap for multiple keys

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I want to have a custom Tab and Shift+Tab listner in my Swing Application. This works fine for a JTextField `textField` when the TAB Key is pressed=>

```
textField.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "Tab");

    textField.getActionMap().put("Tab", new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            navigateDown();
        }
    });
```

But, I want to have the implementation of `Shift + Tab` and I have used this code :-

```
textField.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_TAB), "BackTab");

    textField.getActionMap().put("BackTab", new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            navigateUp();
        }
    });
```

But, this does not works for me. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: By doesn't work, do you mean nothing happens ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your keystroke is incorrect. The second integer is not a keycode but a modifier.

Try it like this:

```
textField.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK), "BackTab");

textField.getActionMap().put("BackTab", new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        navigateUp();
    }
});
```

See also the JavaDoc on `Keystroke.getKeyStroke()`